# How to use java.lang.Number polymorphically

Tags: java

I'm trying to use java.lang.Number polymorphically:
I have a List where I put multiple Double, Integer, etc. instances, and then I want to polymorphically do arithmetic operations on them (for example double every Number).

We don't have the auto-boxing ability with java.lang.Number and I'm not figuring out a better way to do this without the - not so polymorphic - method  multiply(Number n, int factor) in the sample source code that follows... and with this implementation we would need a method for each arithmetic operation (add, subtract, etc.)

---

EDIT - ENHANCE QUESTION: if we think on the java.lang.Number from a abstraction perspective, we would think that any Number can be part of arithmetic operations but yet again it doesn't seem to exist a simple way to add/subtract/multiply/etc x to a list of Number, independently of their type (Integer, Double, Short...)

---

Any better ideias?
Thanks in advance ;)

Sample source code:

```
public class NumberTest {

    private List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new NumberTest().start();

    }

    protected void start() {
        this.fillList();
        Number num;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            num = this.multiply(list.get(i), 2);
            list.set(i, num);
        }

        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    private void fillList() {
        list.add(new Byte((byte) 12));
        list.add(new Short((short) 20));
        list.add(new Integer(30));
        list.add(new Long(40));
        list.add(new Float(50.123));
        list.add(new Double(60.123));
    }

    private Number multiply(Number n, int factor) {
        if (n instanceof Byte) {
            n = n.byteValue() * factor;
        } else if (n instanceof Short) {
            n = n.shortValue() * factor;
        } else if (n instanceof Integer) {
            n = n.intValue() * factor;
        } else if (n instanceof Long) {
            n = n.longValue() * factor;
        } else if (n instanceof Float) {
            n = n.floatValue() * factor;
        } else if (n instanceof Double) {
            n = n.doubleValue() * factor;
        }
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Number num : list) {
            result += num+"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You really can't. You had have a Number. Yay. Unfortunately there is not much to do with, except the instanceof/cast as shown.

Comment: There isn't going to be a better option than the one you're using, which is -- as you've noticed -- pretty crappy.  Most libraries don't mix different `Number` subclasses, and suck it up to write code for each of them when they have to.

Comment: @pst and Louis Unfortunately I start to believe that's the right answer. And I say "unfortunately" because that's not what I was hoping for lol

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see why you can't use Number.doubleValue() and do the math.  What am I missing?

e.g.

```
public Double multiply(Number n, double factor) {
   return new Double(n.getDoubleValue() * factor);
}
```

EDIT ADDED:

@amano has clarified that he wants to change the Objects in the existing List, while *maintaining their original type*.  I guess my first question is, "why"?  His example uses a `Byte`.  Multiplying a Byte times most anything will often result in an overflow.  Adding a `double` to an `Integer` will lose precision.  Subtracting an `integer` from a `Byte` and forcing the result back into a `Byte` will usually give a wrong result.  Dividing an Integer by an integer will usually lose precision (e.g. 3/2 = 1, not 1.5).  Unless you need absolute perfect precision (say, for money) the most mathematically correct solution is to always convert to a double and keep the result as a double.  Yes, there will be minor rounding errors but nothing like 3/2 = 1, or (byte)23 - 665544 = who knows what as a byte?

And why would you care that the value was originally a Byte?  When you make a big deal about wanting to treat it as a Number?  Numbers in, Numbers (technically, Doubles) out.

So I understand better but I'm still missing something.  The constraint that the values remain of the same original type causes inaccuracies, plus a **lot more work.**  If you insist on that constraint, yes, you will have to do a lot of `instanceof`.

Comment: Hello :)Because then we would lose the abstraction of List<Number> and end up with a List<Double>.
If that was what we intended then we would rather use List<Double> in the first place and we wouldn't even need the multiply method since we could use auto-boxing directly.

Comment: Also, doubles have precision problems that could cause issues in some instances where you're looking for an integer value. If you were going to go that route you'd probably want to use BigDecimal instead---which also have precision problems, but have some built-in facilities to handle potential issues.

Comment: @amano  The input list is still a List<Number>.  There is something about your question I still don't understand.

Comment: @user949300 yes the list would still be List<Number> but after updating it with a method like yours it would only contain Double objects. i.e. Integer, Short, Long, Byte, etc. they would all be converted to Double and so loosing their initial type. Has the question states the idea is to use polymorphism - do the arithmetic operations independently of their subtype and keep those subtypes. Do you understand now? if not, try and expand your doubts ;)

Comment: and of course with those conversions we would also start getting precision problems has @Keith stated. But lets not focus on precision since its not the main issue at hands.

Comment: @user949300 your "edit added" section: I wouldn't call it a constraint because the question is about polymorphism and so keeping the objects on their initial type is implied. 
The example source code is not realistic, notice I've included all the wrapper primitive types to make the point clearer (in a real scenario we could just use Integer and Doubles for ex). 
Has mentioned before - lets not waste energies with precision, that's business logic dependent - polymorphism with java.lang.Number is the core of the question.
Sum up: there's no instanceof alternative.
Thanks for everyone efforts :)

Comment: @amano  If the Numbers were mutable it might make more sense to retain their type.  But since they are immutable and have to be replaced, to my way of thinking their type is no longer very informative.  YMMV.

Comment: @user949300 Yes I understand your point and its because of all this Number wrapper classes peculiarities (with autoboxing and immutable that make them different from most regular classes), that I was trying to see if there was a simple way of doing these things with them. Not really looking for a workaround, since the example source code also works and we can implement it in many different ways.
My starting point was "if its a Number I can add something to it or multiply, etc" and each subtype has its own logic.. Integers would truncate decimals etc. All in all a very useful discussion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mirror the Number class hierarchy: write your own NumberWrapper class and for each primitive write a specialized class that knows the actual type and can perform the proper operations.

Late night edit: of course, you could always just use Number#doubleValue() and do your processing only with doubles...

Comment: Yes but we would lose the abstraction of List<Number> and end up with a List<Double>.
I was hoping there was a more direct way of doing this... if we think on the java.lang.Number from a abstraction perspective, we would think that any Number can be part of arithmetic operations but yet again it doesn't seem to exist a  simple way to add/subtract/multiply x to a list of Number, independently of their type (Integer, Double, Short...) :/
I start to agree with the first comments: @pst "We have a Number. Yay. Unfortunately there is not much to do with it" :|

Comment: You will need to understand that Number and its subclasses are immutable - you cannot change them. That is by design. Now, your design wants to use the built-in classes in ways *explicitly* denied by their design. When that happens to me, I take a step back and reconsider what I am doing (in a more general sense), because the guys that wrote these classes are way smarter than me and thought long and hard about them.

Comment: yes I share of your opinion. Just wanted to make sure  I wasn't missing something before exploring other paths. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tassos, except that writing all of that sounds quite tedious...

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you might try using something like this: http://code.google.com/p/generic-java-math/. I've never used this library myself but it looks like what you need.

Comment: Yes, will have a look on the library although I was hoping there was a direct way of doing this out of the box :/ Thanks :)